# How to change UIImageView with a button in a another view

Tags: uiimageview

I've search the web a day for it but I can't find it:
How Can I change a UIImageView with a button in a another view on Xcode.
I'm new to Xcode.

Comment: Ignoring the names of the classes for a second, what effect are you attempting to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your header file in the ImageView ViewController, and connect it:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;
```

Add to the other ViewController's .m file (don't forget to import your first file):

```
- (IBAction)btnPressed {

    TheOtherViewController *vc = [[TheOtherViewController alloc] init];
    vc.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"MyImage"];

}
```